# program that sums all odd numbers between 1 and 100

Tags: java, logic

Trying to create a program that sums  all the odd numbers between 1 and 100 together, displays it, then shows the average. I can't figure out why the loop cuts off early. Super new to this too, so please go easy :p

```
int sum = 0;
double average;
double lowerbound = 1;
double upperbound = 100;
double number = lowerbound;
double remainder = 1;

//loop
    while(number<= upperbound)
        if (remainder == 1){
            sum += number;
            remainder = number%2;
            System.out.println(number);
            number++;
        }else{
            number++;
    }


average = sum/upperbound;

System.out.println();
System.out.println ("These are your sums and averages");

System.out.println (sum);
System.out.println (average);
```

}

Comment: You should be finding the remainder of the current number. Here you're checking the remainder of the previous number. Once the remainder becomes 0, the loop simply ends because no further changes are made.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is your remainder part. You should calculate it **directly**:

```
while(number <= upperbound){
    if (number % 2 == 1){
        sum += number;
        System.out.println(number);
    }
    number++;
}
```

What happens with your code is:
`remainder` starts of as 1. On the first loop `number` is also 1. So you enter the `if` case and you calculate the new `remainder` which is going to be `1%2 = 1`. So in the next run you update remainder to be

```
remainder = 2%2 = 0`.    //number = 2
```

However, since your `remainder` variable is now set to 0, you will never enter the `if` case again and therefore **never update** your `remainder`. (So the loop doesn't end any earlier, you just skip everthing inside of it)

Also notice that you don't need the `else` case, since you are increasing `number` in both the `if` and the `else`

Comment: keiwan, you sir are amazing

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the remainder for every value that you are calculating.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int sum = 0;
    double average;
    double lowerbound = 1;
    double upperbound = 100;
    double number = lowerbound;
    //double remainder = 1;

    //loop
    while(number<= upperbound)
        if (number%2==1){
            sum += number;
            //remainder = number%2;
            System.out.println(number);
            number++;
        }else{
            number++;
        }


    average = sum/upperbound;

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println ("These are your sums and averages");

    System.out.println (sum);
    System.out.println (average);
}
```